# MutationObserver fails sometimes unless the Developer Toolbox is opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, mutation-observers

I created a Chrome Extension that removes/alters some elements from a page while its loading

The condition inside contentScript.js

> if (toListen.includes("elementsTable"))

fails sometimes when I reload the page. It works when I reload the extension or if the Chrome Developer Toolbox is opened. It also works if I hard reload the page.

If I print toListen, it always include "elementsTable", even when the condition above its not triggered.

What is it causing this?

contentScrip.js

```
let mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

//chrome.storage contains options["elementsTable"]
async function retrieveStorage(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(key, resolve);
    })
}

function onMutation(mutations) {
    for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
        for (const n of addedNodes) {
            if (n.tagName) {
                if (toListen.includes("elementsTable")) {
                    if (n.tagName == 'TABLE' && $(n).attr("bgcolor") == "#555576") {
                        console.log("doing something")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function observe() {
    mo.observe(document, {
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true,
        childList: true
    });
}

function listenThread() {
    onMutation([{ addedNodes: [document.documentElement] }]);
    observe();
};

async function start() {
    await retrieveStorage()
        .then((result) => {
            $.each(result.options, function (option) {
                toListen.push(option);
            })
            listenThread();
        })
};

start();
```

The manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "xxx",
  "description": "xxxx",
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "host_permissions": [
      "https://*.xxxx.com/*", 
      "https://*.xxxx.com/*"
    ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.xxxx.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["/static/thirdParty/jquery-3.6.3.min.js", "/static/contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "static/background.js"
  },
  "action": {
  "manifest_version": 3
}
```